# Homestead: Folder mapping to the wrong document root

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant

I'm using Laravel Homestead to VM into my dev environment. I recently created a new mapping (the `/Website/Site/` directory) in my Homestead.yaml whenever I go to `site.app` page , I'm redirected to the /tasks page which was set in another project (`/Laravel`). (This results in an error, since the page isn't there). Here is my Homestead.yaml file:

```
folders:
   - map: /Users/me/Homestead/Code/Laravel
     to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel
   - map: /Users/me/Homestead/Code/Larabook
     to: /home/vagrant/Code/Larabook
   - map: /Users/me/Homestead/Code/Website/Site
     to: /home/vagrant/Code/Website

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
    - map: larabook.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Larabook/public
    - map: site.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Website/public

variables:
   - key: APP_ENV
     value: local
```

The Laravel contains the route where the index page is redirected and the Website directory is the new project that is just a fresh install of Laravel and nothing else. Here is some of the Server/Request Data error output:

```
SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public/index.php
SCRIPT_NAME     /index.php
REQUEST_URI     /tasks
DOCUMENT_URI    /index.php
DOCUMENT_ROOT   /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
```

Here is the route.php for the project in Laravel/ (i.e. the old project)

```
 Route::get('/', function(){
    return Redirect::to('tasks');
 });
```

Why is a fresh install of Laravel being redirected by a project in a different directory?

## SOLUTION

1. `vagrant reload --provision`

or, more drastically

2. from `~/Homestead` run `vagrant destroy` then `vagrant up`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I ran into this issue too.

Presumedly, the changes in `Homestead.yaml` file are being ignored. So, I resolved to refresh it.

**! REVISED SOLUTION THAT DOES NOT DESTROY YOUR MACHINE**

*My solution below is inadequate because it destroys your existing machine. See this solution first!*

> Once your Homestead environment is provisioned and running, you may want to add additional Nginx sites for your Laravel applications. You can run as many Laravel installations as you wish on a single Homestead environment. There are two ways to do this: First, you may simply add the sites to your Homestead.yaml file and then run vagrant provision.
>
> Alternatively, you may use the serve script that is available on your Homestead environment. To use the serve script, SSH into your Homestead environment and run the following command...

http://laravel.com/docs/homestead#daily-usage

Per the [Laravel.io forum](http://laravel.io/forum/05-18-2014-homestead-adding-new-sites-vagrant-destroy) the better solution is to run `vagrant reload --provision`.

See also

*[Vagrant Docs](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/)

**OLD SOLUTIONS: USE AS LAST RESORT**

Try these solutions:

1. from `~/Homestead` run `vagrant reload` then `vagrant up`

or, more drastically

2. from `~/Homestead` run `vagrant destroy` then `vagrant up`

**OPTION 2 DESTROYS YOUR SERVER AND ITS DATABASES**

Note: I resorted to step 2.

Comment: Thank you! I also had to resort to

`vagrant destroy && vagrant up`

Comment: `vagrant reload --provision` worked for me.  Basically just forced to re-read the `homestead.yaml` file

Answer (score 10):

You can run `homestead up --provision` to force the reload of the Homestead.yaml file.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a running homestead instance, simply issue the command `homestead provision` from your local machine.

Comment: In Homestead 5.2 `homestead provision` is the official method. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead#adding-additional-sites

Answer (score 1):

I could fix that issue using the `serve` command provided with the homestead box.
When you're connected to the VM run:

`serve personal.local /home/vagrant/projects/personal/personal-site/public`

without the need to reboot the VM.
I've tried `vagrant reload --provision` and it reloads the yaml file but seems not the ngnix configuration.